# Book about outcasts from Earth

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book where outcasts from Earth settle on some planet and eventually form seven or so guilds/families/kingdoms/nations. Each nation was known for some special trait. One nation could regenerate almost any wound. Another nation was of spies and could go invisible (?). One nation controlled time to an extent... etc. The name of the book was something like 'outcast' but not that word, only a similar word.

Comment: There isn't enough data here to be certain, so I'm left with an intuitive guess: Card's novel *Treason*.

Comment: definitely TREASON!

Comment: Yessir`````````

Comment: Yea, sounds like Treason to me.

Comment: I'm amused that someone named "Ender" is asking about a book that turns out to be another of Card's novels.

Comment: @FakeName I took the name Ender for a reason. ;-) I love card, and had honestly forgotten he wrote treason hehh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the book is **Treason** by **Orson Scott Card**